# Use DirectoryInfo on web server

Tags: .net

i would like to list the files and folder on a remote web sever (http) using DirectoryInfo. I get an error when i do:

```
 DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\myservert\parantFolder\FilesFolder");
 FileInfo[] dirFiles = myDir.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

What am i doing wrong. Would be grateful for every assistance.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [list the files and folder on a remote web sever (http).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662073/list-the-files-and-folder-on-a-remote-web-sever-http)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because DirectoryInfo is meant for use with the local file system or Windows File Shares (not shares over HTTP).

As a side not, the syntax you provide is not a share over HTTP. That syntax would look for a windows share on the myservert server in the FilesFolder subdirectory of the parantFolder share.

Comment: Thanks. What could i use for shares over HTTP?

Comment: @user440942 - There's no good way to do this over HTTP (especially since web server administrators can disable directory/file listing). If you have control over the Web Server, the easiest method may be to enable WebDAV and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to do it for a remote server over HTTP.

If you are using UNC path (like \\server) you need to make sure you have required permissions on that server and the folder.

UNC path refers to a shared server within network and not an HTTP server.

PS: You may consider using [DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos.aspx) this can list entire directory and sub-directories for you.

Comment: I should be doing this for a remote server over HTTP. Would DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos be the right option?